# Should all relations be defined?

Tags: mysql, laravel, symfony, orm, relational-database

Should all relations be defined? In this case, should the "company-advertising" relation also be defined? I mean the advantage is that you do not need to join many tables. What is right?

```
company 1 - n person

person 1 - n advertising

(company 1 - n advertising)
```

company:

```
id | name
1  | xcompany  
2  | ycompany
```

person:

```
id | name     | company_id
1  | xperson  | 1
2  | yperson  | 2
```

advertising:

```
id | name     | person_id
1  | xad      | 1
2  | yad      | 2

advertising->person()->company();

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    advertising
        LEFT JOIN
    person ON advertising.person_id = person.id
        LEFT JOIN
    company ON person.company_id = company.id;
```

vs advertising:

```
id | name     | person_id | company_id
1  | xad      | 1         | 1
2  | yad      | 2         | 2

$advertising->company();

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    advertising
        LEFT JOIN
    company ON advertising.company_id = company.id;
```

Comment: I believe you are thinking about DB denormalization, which is a valid technique but should be applied only when needed:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization

Comment: Although I consider this question quite opinion based, the solution within laravel is quite clear: [HasManyThrough](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasManyThrough.php) relation

Comment: denormalize only when you have large scale application and need improve performance, otherwise, keep normalize and save you a lot of time.

Comment: Check if [polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Since an advertising is mainly associated with a person I would associate only the advertising -> person relationship. However this is my opinion on a simple scenario and it keeps things simple.